# What is the time/space complexity of this algorithm to get all the sub arrays of an array divided by a given number

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion, big-o

I am writing a function that takes an array and an integer number and returns an array of subarrays. The number of subarrays is exact the integer number passed to the function. And the subarrays have to be continuous, meaning the original order of items in the array has to be preserved. Also no subarray can be empty. They have to have at least one item in it. For example:

```js
const array = [2,3,5,4]
const numOfSubarray = 3

const subarrays = getSubarrays(arraym numOfSubarray)
```

In this case `subarrays` is this:

```
[
  [[2, 3], [5], [4]],
  [[2], [3, 5], [4]],
  [[2], [3], [5, 4]],
]
```

Here is my attempt:

```js
function getSubarrays(array, numOfSubarray) {
  const results = []

  const recurse = (index, subArrays) => {
    if (index === array.length && subArrays.length === numOfSubarray) {
      results.push([...subArrays])
      return
    }
    if (index === array.length) return

    // 1. push current item to the current subarray
    // when the remaining items are more than the remaining sub arrays needed

    if (array.length - index - 1 >= numOfSubarray - subArrays.length) {
      recurse(
        index + 1,
        subArrays.slice(0, -1).concat([subArrays.at(-1).concat(array[index])])
      )
    }
    // 2. start a new subarray when the current subarray is not empty

    if (subArrays.at(-1).length !== 0)
      recurse(index + 1, subArrays.concat([[array[index]]]))
  }

  recurse(0, [[]], 0)
  return results
}
```

Right now it seems to be working. But I wanted to know what is the **time/space complexity** of this algorithm. I think it is definitely slower than `O(2^n)`. Is there any way to improve it? Or any other solutions we can use to improve the algorithm here?

Comment: *Why* do you " think it is definitely slower than O(2^n)"?

Comment: Do you know how many "subarrays" there are?  That would give you a lower bound on the complexity.

Comment: Is `[2], [3], [5]` also a valid subarray? Or is one of the constraints that the subarrays have to be disjoint and the union has to be equal to the original array?

Comment: In your example, you are not returning an array of subarrays, you return an array of arrays of subarrays (3D). Is the problem actually about returning ALL valid combinations of subarrays? I think at this point there are too many questions, so please give us a formal problem definition.

Comment: In your example, why isn't `[[2], [3, 5], [4]]` a valid subarray? is this a typo?

Comment: @Markus `[[2], [3], [5]]` is not a valid subarray as it doesn't include all the items in the original array. Not sure what you meant by "disjoint" though.

Comment: @Berthur sorry I think I didn't do a good job explaining the question. Yes it is not an array of subarrays, rather an array of all the possibilities, where every possibility means another array of subarrays divided by the number `numOfSubarray`.

Comment: @Markus sorry `[[2], [3, 5], [4]]` is one of the valid combinations. I updated my question and added it.

Answer (score 3):

<del>You can't get an answer down to anything like `2n`, I'm afraid.  This grows much faster than that, because the answer has to do with the binomial coefficients, whose definitions have fundamental factorial parts, and whose [approximations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Both_n_and_k_large) involve terms like `nn`.</del>

<del>Your solution seems likely to be worse than necessary, noted because of the exponential number of calls required to solve the simplest case, when `numOfSubarrays` is `1`, and you should just be able to return `[array]`.  But as to full analysis, I'm not certain.</del>

*As the first comment shows, the above analysis is dead wrong.*

However, if your're interested in another approach, here's how I might do it, based on the same insight others have mentioned, that the way to do this is to find all sets of `numOfSubarrays` indices of the positions between your values, and then convert them to your final format:

```js
const choose = (n, k) => 
  k == 0
    ? [[]]
  : n == 0
    ? []
    : [... choose (n - 1, k), ... choose (n - 1, k - 1). map (xs => [...xs, n])]

const breakAt = (xs) => (ns) =>
  [...ns, xs .length] .map ((n, i) => xs .slice (i == 0 ? 0 : ns [i - 1], n))

const subarrays = (xs, n) =>
  choose (xs .length - 1, n - 1) .map (breakAt (xs))


console .log (subarrays ([2, 3, 5, 4], 3) // combine for easier demo
  .map (xs => xs .map (ys => ys .join ('')) .join('-')) //=> ["23-5-4", "2-35-4", "2-3-54"]
)

console .log (subarrays ([2, 3, 5, 4], 3)) // pure result
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here, `choose (n, k)` finds all the possible ways to choose `k` elements from the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, ..., `n`.  So, for instance, `choose (4, 2)` would yield `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]`.

`breakAt` breaks an array into sub-arrays at a set of indices.  So

```js
breakAt ([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) ([3, 5])
//                3     5  ///=> [[8, 6, 7], [5, 3], [0, 9]]
```

And `subarrays` simply combines these, subtracting one from the array length, subtracting one from `numOfSubarrays`, calling `choose` with those two values, and then for each result, calling `breakAt` with the original array and this set of indices.

Even here I haven't tried to analyze the complexity, but since the output is factorial, the process will take a factorial amount of time.

Comment: The Wikipedia link you mention approximates (2n choose n) ~ 2^(2n) / sqrt(n* pi) <= 2^(2n). It shows that binomial coefficients grow slower than exponential with the base `2`

Comment: @yjay: You're very right.  I've updated the above to remove the shoddy analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely split a list of `n` elements into `k` disjunct, continuous sub-lists this is like placing `k-1` split points into the `n-1` gaps between the elements:

```
2 | 3 | 5   4
2 | 3   5 | 4
2   3 | 5 | 4
```

In combinatorics this is taking `k-1` from `n-1`. So I think the result size of the ouput will be `n-1 take k-1 = (n-1)! / ((k-1)! * (n-k)!)`. Thus the complexity is something polynomial like `O(n^(k-1))` for constant `k`. If you don't fix `k` but raise it with `n` like `k = n/2` the complexity will get exponential.

I don't think that you can improve this, because the output's size is increasing by this complexity.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The number of solutions is bound to (as @gimix mentioned) binomial coefficient, so if I understand correctly it's pessimistically exponential
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas.

If I'm not mistaken that makes your algorithm this exponential * n (for each element of each solution) * n (because on nearly every step you copy array which length might be dependent on `n`).

- fix second if - only call recurse if subArrays.length < numOfSubarrays
- you are copying arrays a lot - slice, concat, spread operator - all of those create new arrays. If for every solution (which length might be depending on `n`) on every step you copy this solution (which I think is happening here) you multiply the complexity by `n`.
- the space complexity is also exponential * `n` - you store the exponential number of solutions, possibly of length dependent on `n`. Using a generator and returning one solution at the time could greatly improve that. As @gimix mentioned the combinations might be the simplest way to do it. Combinations generator in python: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

## Dwelling on complexity:

I think you are right about the slower than exponential complexity, but - bare with me - how much do you know about Fibonacci's sequence? ;)

Let's consider input:

```
array = [1, 2, ..., n]
numOfSubarrays = 1
```

We can consider the recursive calls a binary tree with `if` 1. guarding the left child (first `recurse` call) and `if` 2. guarding the right child (second `recurse` call).

For each recurse call `if` 1. will be fulfilled - there are more items than sub arrays needed.

Second `if` will be true only if current sub array has some elements. It's a tricky condition - it fails if, and only if, it succeeded one frame higher - an empty array has been added at the very beginning (except for the root call - it has no parent). Speaking in terms of a tree, it means we are in the right child - the parent must have just added an empty sub array as a current. On the other hand, for the left child parent has just pushed (yet another?) element to the current sub array and we are sure the if 2. will succeed.

Okay, but what does it say about the complexity?

Well, we can count the number of nodes in the tree, multiply by the number of operations they perform - most of them a constant number - and we get the complexity. So how many are there?

I'll keep track of left and right nodes separately on every level. It's gonna be useful soon. For convenience I'll ignore root call (I could treat it as a right node - it has empty sub array - but it messes up the final effect) and start from level 1 - the left child of the root call.

r<sub>1</sub> = 0
l<sub>1</sub> = 1

As a left node (sub array isn't empty) it has two children:

r<sub>2</sub> = 1
l<sub>2</sub> = 1

Now, the left node always has two children (1. is always fulfilled; 2. is true because parent pushed element to current sub array) and the right node has only the left child:

r<sub>3</sub> = r<sub>2</sub> + l<sub>2</sub> = 1 + 1 = 2
l<sub>3</sub> = r<sub>2</sub> = 1

we could continue. The results are:

| l | r |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |

well... it's oddly familiar, isn't it?

Okay, so apparently, the complexity is O(Σ(F<sub>i</sub> + F<sub>i-1</sub>) where 1 <= i <= n).

Alright, but what does it really mean?
There is a very cool [prove](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sum-fibonacci-numbers/) that S(n) - sum of the Fibonacci numbers from 0 to n is equal F(n+2) - 1. It simplifies the complexity to:

```
O(S(n) + S(n-1)) = O(F(n+2) - 1 + F(n+1) - 1) = O(F(n+3) - 2) = O(F(n+3))
```

We can forget about the +3 since F(n+3) < 2 * F(n+2) < 4 * F(n+1) < 8 * F(n).

The final question, is Fibonacci sequence exponential? Yes and no apparently.
The is no number that would fulfil the x<sup>n</sup> = F(n) - the value oscillates between 2 and √2, because for F(n+1) < 2 * F(n) < F(n+2).

It's proven though, that lim(n->∞) F(n+1) / F(n) = φ - the golden ratio. It means the O(F(n)) = O(φ<sup>n</sup>). (Actually, you copy arrays a lot, so it's more like  O(φ<sup>n</sup>*n))

How to fix it? You could check if there isn't too many arrays before recursing in if 2.

Other than that, just as @Markus mentioned, depending on the input, the number of solutions might be exponential, so the algorithm to get them also has to be exponential. But that's not true for every input, so let's keep those cases to minimum :D

Comment: This seems confused as an answer to the question.  The binomial coefficient is not exponential.  See the [next section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Both_n_and_k_large) of that Wikipedia article which shows Stirling's approximation, and note that there is a term of `n ^ n`  in there.   It grows faster than any exponential function.  I'm not sure what you're trying to demonstrate with Fibonacci numbers, but it seems unrelated to the question.  I mean, Fibonacci and Factorial both start with `F` and can be handled with recursion... but that's about it.

Comment: I agree, sorry, got sidetracked :D But I think I'm right about how fast the binomial coefficient grows. A quick argument: (n choose k) = ((n-1) choose k) + ((n-1) choose (k-1)). Which shows that for every n, k there are such t, v that: (n choose k) <= ((n-1) choose t) + ((n-1) choose v). This means that max(n choose k)  <= 2 * max((n-1) choose t), which shows it doesn't grow faster than 2^n. Also the inequality is strict e.g. for n = 1. I'm both annoyed and amused by the joke, haha, cheers!

Comment: It's hard to talk about growth in this way with two mostly independent variables.  Your demonstration is for a fixed `k`.  If we watched, say, `2n choose n`, we will see [something different](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/61).  The existence of the factorials in the closed form solution should suggest that this is super-exponential... Isn't getting side-tracked fun?!

Comment: Your simulation should take `n` as input to both functions - the exponential and the binomial coefficient, but you take `n` as an input to exponential and `2n` as an input to binomial.

Comment: The Wikipedia link you sent also shows that: (2n choose n) ~ (2 ^ (2n)) / sqrt(n * pi) < 2 ^ (2n). It's really amazing, that from a division of factorial comes out something behaving as an exponential :D

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I didn't read past the `n ^ n`.  And an [updated demo](http://link.fourwindssoft.com/62) does demonstrate it.  So we know it's less that `O (2 ^ (2n))` or `O (4 ^ n)`, at least in terms of space, for `2n choose n`.  Since that will be the largest binomial coefficient for `2n`, I guess we can see then that `n choose k` for an arbitrary `k` is bounded by `O (2 ^ n)`.  *Mea culpa*.  Of course none of this really helps analyze the specific algorithm expressed in the OP's code.  But I'm going to go off and remove my foot from my mouth.

Answer (score -1):

The problem can be solved by a different approach:

- compute all the combinations of `numOfSubarray` numbers ranging from 1 to the length of `array`
- each combination is a valid slicing of `array`. For instance, you want to slice the array in your example at positions (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), yielding subarrays `[[2],[3],[5,4]]`, `[[2],[3,5],[4]]`, and `[[2,3],[5],[4]]`

Time complexity is, I believe, O(r(nCr)) where n is (length of array - 1) and r is (number of subarrays - 1).

To visualize how and why it works have a look at the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) technique